# Difference of angle by Y value

Tags: c++, mathematics

This code from game 90s years. For example on scene there is tiger as "item" and main character as "enemy". This code calculate vector or direction of attack tiger to main character. Used fixed point math.

```
#define W2V_SHIFT 14

#define PREDICTIVE_SCALE_FACTOR 14

{
z = (enemy->pos.z_pos + (enemy->speed * PREDICTIVE_SCALE_FACTOR * phd_cos(enemy->pos.y_rot) >> W2V_SHIFT)) - (item->pos.z_pos + (object->pivot_length * phd_cos(item->pos.y_rot) >> W2V_SHIFT));
x = (enemy->pos.x_pos + (enemy->speed * PREDICTIVE_SCALE_FACTOR * phd_sin(enemy->pos.y_rot) >> W2V_SHIFT)) - (item->pos.x_pos + (object->pivot_length * phd_sin(item->pos.y_rot) >> W2V_SHIFT));
}

angle = phd_atan(z, x);

z = abs(z);
x = abs(x);

if (x > z)
info->x_angle = phd_atan(x + (z >> 1), y);
else
info->x_angle = phd_atan(z + (x >> 1), y);
```

x_angle is seems angle from Y position of item relatively to Y position of enemy?

What do this calculations: x + (z >> 1) and z + (x >> 1)? Explain this calculations please.

Answer (score 1):

The code is functionally equivalent to:

`angle = atan(max(x,y) + min(x,y)/2,y);`

Not overly helpful.

### So let's examine it from a different perspective:

This is a variation of axis interlacing used in sorting algorithms:

Say, You have 2 integers X and Y. X0 is the most-significant bit...

using the bit pattern: X0 Y0 X1 Y1 ...

You can approximate the sort on two axes at the same time as if they were a single dimension. Reducing complexity from N^2 to N.

---

The given code does a similar thing for lengths.

It is a very fast, but rather poor approximation of `sqrt(x^2 + z^2)`

In the sorting case above, X0 was arbitrarily chosen to go first. In this case the larger value goes first. `if (x > z)`

The reason for the bit shift is twofold:

1. It keeps the output values from overly exceeding the expected output `(1.0,1.0) = 1.1` instead of returning 2.0, when the actual value is `sqrt(2) = 1.414...`
2. It approximates a rounding effect in log2 space. 2 values with similar MSBs will carry the bits leading to closer to accurate results.

---

The `atan` functions in the 90s were simple lookup-tables so only the most significant values mattered.